# Show input box and store value when each checkbox is clicked separately

Tags: javascript, angular

I am displaying different locations to the front end.
When each location is checked, the User is asked to add the Quantity of stock they want to add in that specific location.

Now I am not sure how to achieve this in angular. Can someone please guide or help me?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Markets to stock and fulfill product</h4>

   <div *ngFor="let location of  (allLocations | async)" class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="{{location}}" id="checkboxCity_">
      <label class="form-check-label">
         {{location}}
       </label>
                    
    <div class="row">
     <div id="stockInput_" style="display: none;">
      <label>Enter Quantity of Stock in this Market (In Units)</label>
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <input placeholder="Stock (In Units)" class="form-control" name="mkt[]" id="stock_">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created it previously in core Javascript and this was what I was creating.

```
{"Houston":"30","New York":"10","Los Angeles":null}
```

So is it possible to achieve it in Angular too?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want. Can you show input and output of your code?

Comment: https://paste.pics/DICC3
I have added the screenshot of the frontend here, The 'Enter Quantity of Stock in this market' only appears once that checkbox is clicked. And once the user add the quantity I want it to create array like this {"Houston":"30","New York":"10","Los Angeles":null}

Comment: can you create stackblitz working sample? it is hard to solve your problem without any code. you put your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-for and send link